# Kogito Springboot App : Input coming in as null

Tags: bpmn, kogito

I have a Java DTO that I'm using as a Process Data variable in my BPMN flow with the tag of input (I have also tried removing the tag altogether). The DTO fields show up in the Swagger UI. For testing, I have just a simple script node as the first thing in the BPMN flow that does a println statement of the variable, which is now printing null after I send my request from the Swagger UI.

[BPMN Process Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRp94.png)
[BPMN Scrpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8s2x.png)

The other odd thing I can't seem to control, is the sample request in the Swagger UI is duplicated:

[Swagger UI Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoxC9.png)

I expect the println statement to print something like this:

FraudCheckRequest input ='{email=test@test.com, billingContactName=Tester, ipAddress=55.555.555.555, phoneNumber=6665552222, sessionId=454354646464, dbaName=Test Company, accountName=TEST, federalTaxId=123456789, billingContactEmail=test@test.com, legalStructure=LLC, mailingAddressLine1=123 Test Lane, mailingCity=test, mailingState=CA, mailingPostalCode=04092, physicalAddressLine1=123 Test Lane, physicalCity=Test, physicalPostalCode=04092, physicalState=CA, transactionId=, programName=Test}'